# knows about extreme anxiety

Tags: word-meaning

The word "know", in the context below, seems to mean "understand (it) by his own experience (that is, Carriello himself is suffering the extreme anxiaty.  Am I on the right track?

Brazilian jiu-jitsu helps those suffering from depression, mental illness or stress, he said, though, despite his obvious physical fitness, Mr. Carriello now **knows about extreme anxiety**.

“I have never been so stressed in my entire life,” he said, reflecting on the repeated visits from the authorities and adding, “If they extend this lockdown we are going to have a civil war.”

Source: [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/11/22/world/europe/England-gyms-covid-lockdown.html?smid=tw-nytimes&smtyp=cur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That it exactly what it means here.

If you look on the google defintion you will see this entry: "have personal experience of (an emotion or situation)." That is the usage here as you have identified.